# The command shortcuts close all windows and temporarily blanks the desktop on my iMac

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, imac

Essentially what happens to my late 2015 iMac is that when I use my command shortcuts and the down arrow **anywhere** (except command+b which just worked), all my windows close and my desktop temporarily becomes blank (no folders or files, just the background).

I have to be honest, I did use [Free Sidecar](https://github.com/ben-z/free-sidecar). Eventually, I got some system prompts saying that the sidecarcore (the application) wasn't working with several applications, including iMessage for some reason. I've tried restarting, checking the system integrity protection, and following the troubleshooting guides from Ben-z's Free Sidecar, but to no avail.

I am running the latest software on 10.15.2 of Catalina, and I have a late 2015 21 inch iMac.

Another symptom is that the clock disappeared from my menu bar, and System Preferences won't let me add it back.

Comment: No question here, so [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/ben-z/free-sidecar#troubleshooting) > 7. "I want to revert to the original SidecarCore"!

Comment: @Allan [According to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210380) SideCar is compatible with iMac (2017-...) and iMac Retina 5K 27“ 2015 but not with the iMac 21" 2015.